# recoding a numerical variable based on a specific criterion in r

Tags: r, recode

I would like to recode a numerical variable based on a cut score criterion. If the cut scores are not available in the variable, I would like to recode the closest smaller value as a cut score. Here is a snapshot of dataset:

```
ids <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
scores <- c(512,531,541,555,562,565,570,572,573,588)
data <- data.frame(ids, scores)
> data
   ids scores
1    1    512
2    2    531
3    3    541
4    4    555
5    5    562
6    6    565
7    7    570
8    8    572
9    9    573
10  10    588

cuts <- c(531, 560, 575)
```

The first cut score (`531`) is in the dataset. So it will stay the same as `531`. However, `560` and `575` were not available. I would like to recode the closest smaller value (`555`) to the second cut score as `560` in the new column, and for the third cut score, I'd like to recode `573` as `575`.

Here is what I would like to get.

```
   ids scores  rescored
1    1    512   512
2    2    531   531
3    3    541   541
4    4    555   560
5    5    562   562
6    6    565   565
7    7    570   570
8    8    572   572
9    9    573   575
10  10    588   588
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: edited. thanks for your careful eye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to find the index with `findInterval` and then get the `pmax` of the  'scores' corresponding to that index with the 'cuts' and updated the 'rescored' column elements on that index

```
i1 <- with(data, findInterval(cuts, scores))
data$rescored <- data$scores
data$rescored[i1] <- with(data, pmax(scores[i1], cuts))
data
#   ids scores rescored
#1    1    512      512
#2    2    531      531
#3    3    541      541
#4    4    555      560
#5    5    562      562
#6    6    565      565
#7    7    570      570
#8    8    572      572
#9    9    573      575
#10  10    588      588
```

Comment: oh, one issue is that this works when the numerical variable is sorted. My full data is not sorted. Is there a quick tweak for that?

Comment: @amisos55  You can `order` the dataset and then apply the `findInterval` i.e. `data <- data[order(data$scores),]`

Comment: I already used 'i1 <- findInterval(cuts, sort(scores))', but is it possible to do it without ordering the dataset? Because I need it without ordering

Comment: @amisos55  An option is to create a sequence column before the order i.e. `data$rn <- seq_len(nrow(data)); data <- data[order(data$scores),]` and then after the `findInterval` reorder based on 'rn'